Can't get hostname for your address flooded in error log even if skip-name-resolve is enabled and many unauth users in processlist in percona 8.0.25
Information about the currently configured percona servers :

We are using percona 8.0.25 server.
Mysql service is running with skip-name-resolve enabled.
host_cache_size=753 but the performance_schema.host_cache table is empty,
All mysql users have host as 10.10.% or actual ip addresses.
The percona server is a master to 5 slaves.
Replicant user is created on master as replicant@'slave_ip_address'.
No hostname based users are present in the mysql.user table. All users have authentication plugin as mysql_native_password.
All of the percona servers master and 5 slaves are aws ec2 instances .
Traffic to these servers come via HAproxy.
We have a mysql user with ip as host used by icinga for monitoring.
Similarly we have a mysql user with ip as host used by grafana for monitoring as well.
On the master server we have systemd-resolved running.
We are used thread handling mechanism on master as percona's pool-of-threads.
When we stop the io_thread of slave servers we could see there are no unauthenticated users on master. As soon as we start io thread we can see multiple unauthenticated users. Is it related to thread handling ? You can check related issues ; https://forums.percona.com/t/percona-mysql8-0-23-unauthenticated-user-after-start-slave/13722, https://forums.percona.com/t/many-unauthenticated-user-thread-after-start-slave/13740
You can find Thread handling related configuration on master as below :

+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value           |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
| create_admin_listener_thread            | OFF             |
| innodb_encryption_threads               | 0               |
| innodb_log_writer_threads               | ON              |
| innodb_parallel_read_threads            | 4               |
| innodb_purge_threads                    | 4               |
| innodb_read_io_threads                  | 4               |
| innodb_thread_concurrency               | 16              |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay               | 0               |
| innodb_write_io_threads                 | 4               |
| max_delayed_threads                     | 20              |
| max_insert_delayed_threads              | 20              |
| myisam_repair_threads                   | 1               |
| mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout       | 60              |
| mysqlx_min_worker_threads               | 2               |
| performance_schema_max_thread_classes   | 0               |
| performance_schema_max_thread_instances | 0               |
| thread_cache_size                       | 400             |
| thread_handling                         | pool-of-threads |
| thread_pool_high_prio_mode              | transactions    | 
| thread_pool_high_prio_tickets           | 4294967295      | 
| thread_pool_idle_timeout                | 60              |
| thread_pool_max_threads                 | 100000          |
| thread_pool_oversubscribe               | 3               | 
| thread_pool_size                        | 8               | 
| thread_pool_stall_limit                 | 500             | 
| thread_stack                            | 286720          |
| thread_statistics                       | OFF             |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
27 rows in set (0.05 sec) 
mysql> show global status like '%thread%';
+------------------------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name                            | Value   |
+------------------------------------------+---------+
| Com_show_thread_statistics               | 0       |
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0       |
| Innodb_master_thread_active_loops        | 4033897 |
| Innodb_master_thread_idle_loops          | 38153   |
| Mysqlx_worker_threads                    | 2       |
| Mysqlx_worker_threads_active             | 0       |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   | 0       |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0       |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0       |
| Threadpool_idle_threads                  | 16      | 
| Threadpool_threads                       | 24      | 
| Threads_cached                           | 0       |
| Threads_connected                        | 75      | 
| Threads_created                          | 29851   | 
| Threads_running                          | 9       | 
+------------------------------------------+---------+


You can find Connection related configuration on master as below :

+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name                                 | Value              |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_connection                      | utf8mb4            |
| collation_connection                          | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| connect_timeout                               | 60                 |
| disconnect_on_expired_password                | ON                 |
| init_connect                                  |                    |
| max_connect_errors                            | 10000              |
| max_connections                               | 3000               |
| max_user_connections                          | 0                  |
| mysqlx_connect_timeout                        | 30                 |
| mysqlx_max_connections                        | 100                |
| performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size | 0                  |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global status like '%conn%';
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name                                         | Value               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Aborted_connects                                      | 16627               |
| Connection_errors_accept                              | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_internal                            | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_max_connections                     | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_peer_address                        | 15350               |
| Connection_errors_select                              | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap                             | 0                   |
| Connections                                           | 8378267             |
| Locked_connects                                       | 0                   |
| Max_used_connections                                  | 570                 |
| Max_used_connections_time                             | 2024-03-11 10:56:56 |
| Mysqlx_connection_accept_errors                       | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connection_errors                              | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_accepted                           | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_closed                             | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_rejected                           | 0                   |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_longest_seen | 0                   |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost         | 0                   |
| Ssl_client_connects                                   | 0                   |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates                              | 0                   |
| Ssl_finished_connects                                 | 0                   |
| Threads_connected                                     | 63                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)


Also the primary master is in master-master replication with one of the 5 slaves.
We are using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS OS for our master server. Slaves have a mix of 16,20 Ubuntu OS.

Issue :

We have observed many unauthenticated users stuck in the master's processlist.
At the same time error is logged as
[Note] [MY-010914] [Server] Aborted connection 8361894 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'connecting host' (Can't get hostname for your address).

Why is percona trying to do reverse dns lookup ? When these unauthenticated users are stuck in the processlist, application faces various mysql exceptions as well as we are not able to connect to the master with mysql client seamlessly.


is a master to 5 slaves.
The terminology changed with 8.0. Please use source/replica.
| Max_used_connections | 570
You should not be using thread pooling. Thread pooling is designed for systems with X0,000+ connections.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496902/mysql-has-gone-away-connection-errors-peer-address-with-high-numbers for why skip-name-resolve has no effect here

